# Install a binary from Tesseract OCR's Docker image using a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, image, dockerfile, tesseract

#### TL;DR

How to install a binary from Tesseract OCR's Docker image using a Dockerfile

#### Problem

I'm trying to install Tesseract OCR's binary from a Docker image into my image. I already made it work for ffmpeg, but I can't seem to figure out how to grab the Tesseract binary. Does anyone have experience with this?

#### Code

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:4.1-alpine as ffmpeg
FROM clearlinux/tesseract-ocr:4.1.0 as tesseract

FROM node:16-alpine

# WORKING: Copy ffmpeg to node container
COPY --from=ffmpeg / /

# NOT WORKING: Copy tesseract to node container
COPY --from=tesseract /bin/tesseract /

WORKDIR '/app'

# Other NodeJS stuff...
```

#### Sources

Library I'm trying to install as a binary: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Docker image I'm currently using to grab the binary from https://hub.docker.com/r/clearlinux/tesseract-ocr

Comment: Copying individual binaries from one Docker image to another has some obvious failure modes, most notably dependencies on files in other directories like `/usr/share` and missing C shared-library dependencies.  Can you use your image's package manager (for an Alpine-based image, `apk`) to install the program that way?

Comment: I will give `apk`  a spin

Comment: `apk` doesn't seem to work correctly, probably because `tesseract-ocr=5.0.1-r1` isn't supported on `node:16-alpine`. I'm running this: `RUN apk update && apk add tesseract-ocr=5.0.1-r1` and gave `ERROR: unable to select packages:`

Comment: Do `RUN apk update && apk add tesseract-ocr`. That'll give you 4.1.3 which is newer than the one in the image you tried to copy from.